# How do I correctly specify model/table name in Doctrine 2 DQL query?

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, doctrine-orm, dql

I've upgraded to Doctrine 2 in my Zend application. I have the following code in a controller:

```
// get instance of entity manager
$em = $this->_helper->Em();

// get instance of query builder
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('g')
->from('Groups', 'g');

$query = $qb->getQuery();   
$aGroups = $query->getResult();
```

However it throws the error: Message:[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'Groups g': Error: Class 'Groups' is not defined.

The entities are in application/models/Entities/

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Side note: you might want to push that query-building code out of the controller and down into a model, a repository, or a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Is `Group` the complete classname? The DQL queries with which I am familiar use the complete class name. Is there some pseudo-namespace on the class, like `Application_Model_Group`,  `Application_Entity_Group`, or some such thing?
2. Is the classname singular `Group` rather than plural `Groups`?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, I'm new to namespaces. The groups class in the Entities folder is declared as: class Groups {...} - So I'm assuming Groups is the complete class name.

Comment: Then it sounds like an autoloading issue. How are you configuring Doctrine during bootstrap?

Comment: Looks like your autoloader expects the class to be within the namespace `Entities`. So the classname might need to be either `Entities\Groups` or `Entities_Groups`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far David. I tried both Entities\Groups and Entities_Groups in the query but the same error is given...

Comment: Remember that the classname that appears in the query has to match the classname as it is defined in `application/models/Groups.php`. According to your autoloader config, seems like it should be `Entities_Groups`.

Comment: @Sid let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1466/discussion-between-david-weinraub-and-sid)